# In GCP, how to create firewall rules to isolate subnets by their IP ranges?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall, vpc

We are using a shared VPC with two subnets (10.65.0.0/16 and 10.66.0.0/16). The shared VPC has connection to on-prem network, so both two subnets can access the resource hosted on on-prem. Since we use one subnet for DEV environment, and the other one for PROD environment, we want to block all traffic between those two subnets. I don't want to manage those firewall rules by using tags or service accounts of each instance hosting on those subnets, since the owner of all projects hosting in those two subnets may not always following the rules, and cause extra communications to clarify. Ideally, I want to create some firewall rules to block the traffic just using those two IP ranges of subnets. To isolate subnets between each other, I need to create a "deny" firewall rule with source "10.65.0.0/16" and distinction "10.66.0.0/16", and another one with source "10.66.0.0/16" and distinction "10.65.0.0/16". For what I saw, in both egress and ingress firewalls, it's only allowed to set IP ranges on either source or distinction, but cannot be both. It looks there is no way to set both source and distinction in a single firewall using CIDR.

I know using peered network can easily cut the traffic between VPCs/subnets. But there is limitation in VPC, that the routing between 2+ layers of peering are terrible, and resources managed by google already involved a layer of peering, so if possible I don't want to involve another layer of peered network. If there are no better ideas, I probably have to use either Tags or Service accounts to create firewalls one by one.

Please share your ideas, or any other way to resolve my problem.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Create multiple firewall rules. One blocking egress and one blocking ingress. As I mentioned on your other question, show what you tried and the problem.

Comment: Give it a try, you will find your idea will not work. In VPC firewall are setting on instance level.  If you create two firewall rules for one ingress and one egress, you will find out that you will blocked the traffic inside each subnet as well. Please don't make assumption, and play around inside a VPC with two subnets a little bit, before answer the question.

Comment: If you configure rules correctly you will only block specified traffic.

Comment: Hi John, in GCP VPC, you can only choose "ALL instances in the network", "Tags", or "service account" to define which instance(s) will be affected, that's why I get difficulty. If you really think you have a solution, please just answer my questions with an example, instead of put a comment based on a assumption. That will help all people. Thanks.

Comment: e.g. if you create a ingress "deny" firewall with source IP range 10.65.0.0/16, and there are two instances 10.65.0.3 and 10.65.0.4, then the traffic between those two instances will be blocked too, which I don't want to. I wish there are a general way to allow all instances in same subnet can talk to each other, and traffic cross subnets are fully blocked. I know using peered network can easily achieve it. But there is limitation in VPC, that the routing between 2+ layers of peering are terrible, and resources managed by google already involved a layer peering, so cannot involve another one

Comment: For example, rules have a priority. One rule can block all traffic between subnets and another rule with a higher priority can allow traffic from one specific address. The higher priority rule will be checked first and allow the traffic. You can then create multiple rules for multiple allowed hosts.

Comment: you cannot using one rule to block all traffic between subnets. Rule is defined on whole VPC scope, but assigned on instance level. There is no way to set on an individual subnet level. That's why I am posting this question and see if other people have better ideas.

Comment: Yes, you can. Rules have a source address which can be a CIDR. Instead of arguing, show what you have tried and the result. Do **not** post multiple questions asking the same thing. You will get downvoted and closed. Start by reading these guides: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: let's use ingress firewall as an example. Yes, I can define source CIDR. If I want to block traffic from 10.66.x.x to 10.65.x.x, I should define the source as 10.66.x.x, but it will also cause a VM with IP 10.66.0.Y cannot get incoming request from another VM with 10.66.0.Z, Can you see that? It's all because, the firewall rule of VPC is working on each instance individually. Instances in same subnet cannot talk to each other natively. For those instances, which are all hosted on 10.66.0.0/16, the traffic between them will be blocked too, which is not what I want.

Comment: Hi John, I opened a ticket to Google Tech support for this question. The answer didn't surprise me. They suggest using tags with ip ranges together to achieve this. e.g. - allow all [ingress], Targets tags: vmGroup1, Source IPv4 or tags: Subnet CIDR or vmGroup1

Answer (score 1):

Consulted Google tech support for this question. Their suggestion is no surprise. It can not be done by setting source IP CIDR and distinction CIDR. Their suggestion is using "Tags" + "resource IP ranges".

e.g. - allow all [ingress], Targets tags: vmGroup-1, Source IPv4 : CIDR of vmGroup-1

Basically, going through this way instead of create "deny" firewalls caused by one advantage of VPC, and one limitation of VPC. The advantage is: The advantage is: In VPC the traffic is blocked between any instances naturally, even they are in the same subnet, firewalls are created in VPC but working on each instance individually, it's like each instance has its own firewall. The limitation is: so far, VPC don't allow firewall be created with both source and distinction IP ranges be defined.